# What exactly Scatter Plot in Core Plot?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot

What exactly Scatter Plot in Core Plot?
In my application,I am plotting values & join them except null values.If the null value is there in between then the plots are not joined.Is it the right way to plot values in Scatter plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the way scatter plot works in coreplot. Scatter plot is represented by joining the co-ordinate points using a line. If some data is missing, it will be represented by a broken link in scatter plot.

Alternatively you can try to represent a null value using zero value for that corresponding axis value and it can be represented as a sudden dip in the graph at that portion, but that again depends on your specific requirement.